# How to join the two table vertically with different header name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 table one is this:
[image]

Another table is this:
[image]

I wish to replace the column name of the test and p replace by s and both table are join together like this:

[image]

Anyone can share with me how to join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine two data frames ignoring column names, you can use `numpy.concatenate`, and manually pass the column names in later:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1], "B": [2]})
B = pd.DataFrame({"A":[3], "C": [4]})

A
#   A   B
#0  1   2

B
#   A   C
#0  3   4

pd.DataFrame(pd.np.concatenate((A, B)), columns=["A", "D"])
#   A   D
#0  1   2
#1  3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also merge two data frames by specifying the how parameter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Indicator":["ClassH", "ClassH"], "WW":[201648, 201649]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Indicator": ["ClassH", "ClassH"], "WW":[201650, 201651]}) 

merge_df = df.merge(df1, how="outer") # use union of keys from both frames 
print(merge_df)

   Indicator      WW
0    ClassH  201648
1    ClassH  201649
2    ClassH  201650
3    ClassH  201651
```